# Recreate Siri Button Glow Animation

Tags: ios, core-animation, quartz-2d

Is there any way of duplication the siri button glow animation? It looks absolutely gorgeous, but I have no idea at the moment how to start... are there online preformatted pngs that are rotated? or is it done with CoreAnimation?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe that Siri animation is made with CAEmitterLayer and CAEmitterCell and then animated with core animation, but I might be totally wrong. Here's some code that imitates the effect:

```
// create emitter layer
self.emitterLayer = [CAEmitterLayer layer];
self.emitterLayer.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.bounds.size.width,  self.view.bounds.size.height);

self.emitterLayer.emitterMode = kCAEmitterLayerOutline;
self.emitterLayer.emitterShape = kCAEmitterLayerLine;
self.emitterLayer.renderMode = kCAEmitterLayerAdditive;
[self.emitterLayer setEmitterSize:CGSizeMake(4, 4)];

// create the ball emitter cell
CAEmitterCell *ball = [CAEmitterCell emitterCell];
ball.color = [[UIColor colorWithRed:111.0/255.0 green:80.0/255.0 blue:241.0/255.0 alpha:0.10] CGColor];
ball.contents = (id)[[UIImage imageNamed:@"ball.png"] CGImage]; // ball.png is simply an image of white circle
[ball setName:@"ball"];

self.emitterLayer.emitterCells = [NSArray arrayWithObject:ball];
[self.view.layer addSublayer:self.emitterLayer];

float factor = 1.5; // you should play around with this value
[self.emitterLayer setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:(factor * 500)] forKeyPath:@"emitterCells.ball.birthRate"];
[self.emitterLayer setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:factor * 0.25] forKeyPath:@"emitterCells.ball.lifetime"];
[self.emitterLayer setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:(factor * 0.15)] forKeyPath:@"emitterCells.ball.lifetimeRange"];


// animation code
CAKeyframeAnimation* circularAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"emitterPosition"];
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGRect pathRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 200); // define circle bounds with rectangle
CGPathAddEllipseInRect(path, NULL, pathRect);
circularAnimation.path = path;
CGPathRelease(path);
circularAnimation.duration = 2;
circularAnimation.repeatDuration = 0;
circularAnimation.repeatCount = 3;
circularAnimation.calculationMode = kCAAnimationPaced;
[self.emitterLayer addAnimation:circularAnimation forKey:@"circularAnimation"];
```

CAEmitterCell and CAEmitterLayer classes have many properties so check out the docs for more.

Comment: self.fireEmitter is missing the context here

Comment: I've forgot to edit those lines when copying code. It should have been self.emitterLayer. I've fixed it.

Answer (score 6):

I suggest you do it with PNGs which are displayed one by one such that a smooth animation results. It's way easier than programming a coded animation. The button has already been recreated by Arron Hunt: [Siri Button Photoshop File](http://dribbble.com/shots/293480-Siri)

Btw. A sprite animation is really easy to implement:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSArray * imageArray  = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"4.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"5.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"6.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"7.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"8.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"9.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"10.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"11.png"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"12.png"],
                            nil];
    UIImageView * ryuJump = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:
        CGRectMake(100, 125, 150, 130)];
    ryuJump.animationImages = imageArray;
    ryuJump.animationDuration = 1.1;
    ryuJump.contentMode = UIViewContentModeBottomLeft;
    [self.view addSubview:ryuJump];
    [ryuJump startAnimating];
}
```

Source: http://www.icodeblog.com/2009/07/24/iphone-programming-tutorial-animating-a-game-sprite/

Comment: You've got a point... So implementing enough PNGs for a rotation animation would be a way. I always thought that such things ought to be made with CoreAnimation because it is easier to modify then. The link is great! I will take a look on that!

Comment: Have a look at my edited answer for a sample code which does a sprite animation. Good luck

Comment: @Lightforce , Can anybody have set of PNG Images for this PSD File, i  don't have any Photoshop knowledge to extract the images.Can any one upload it some where so it is easy for every one to use it.Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

UIImageView has a property called animationImages that you can use to specify a list of images that it will play in sequence, like an animated GIF. That's probably the easiest way to do it if you want to precisely control the effect.

Something similar could also be done with CoreAnimation by using a single image and animating its view.transform property using CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(angle).

Comment: That was my first thought as well... making a glow image with a gradient and alpha of 0 at one and in a circle shape and then rotating that thing... but I am not sure if that would produce that glowing effect... because it would still look kind of static?

Comment: You might want to vary the alpha over time as well, so fade the alpha in and out as it rotates to make it appear to pulse a bit.