# iOS Create Siri icon and animation

Tags: ios, core-animation, siri

I have an app that uses voice input and I would like to create an icon that replicate's the look and feel of the Siri mic.

Are there any tutorials that outline how to go about this? I'm fine with getting access to the mic levels, its more what techniques to use to perform the animations (e.g. is a separate image required for each level / for the waiting state (where a 'fireball' is created)).

Comment: I disagree with @KevinBallard. There are several apps that do something similar. Although you need to be careful on the actual images you use, it can be done and be accepted into the app store. There are (or used to be) TONS of FART apps ;—P

Comment: Im just saying that duplicating something that is already in the app store won't necessarily get the app rejected.

Comment: possible duplicate: <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8975239/recreate-siri-button-glow-animation>

Answer (score 3):

The Siri mike animation seems like fairly vanilla Core Animation.

My guess is that it uses a static image of the gradient that fills the mic, set behind an oval mask. The gradient is shifted up for higher voice levels and down for lower voice levels, with a pretty short duration animation using a linear timing curve.

I did something sort of similar for a client who was developing a voice recognition application.

As for the rotating "thinking" animation, that looks like a simple rotation animation of a static image.